# Find the total number of times each of a possible range of values occurs across three separate variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data which looks like this:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

Codes = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9)
Codes2 = c(Codes, rep(9, 100))

data <- data.frame(
  MASTER_HCU_DI = do.call(paste0, Map(stri_rand_strings, n=100, length=c(4, 3),
                                      pattern = c('[A-Z]', '[0-9]'))),
  CODE_1 = sample(Codes, 100, replace = T))
data %<>%
  mutate(CODE_2 = if_else(CODE_1 == 9, 9, sample(Codes2, 100, replace = T)),
         CODE_3 = if_else(CODE_2 == 9, 9, sample(Codes2, 100, replace = T)))
```

What I want to do is find the total number of people with each of the possible values of CODE_1, CODE_2, and CODE_3; across all three Codes.

Where all of someone's CODE start with a 9, they are counted as missing. Otherwise, I'd like to ignore the CODE values which start with a 9.

This code does what I want, but seems cumbersome:

```
data %<>%
  mutate(Sum_grp1 = if_else(CODE_1 == 1 | CODE_2 == 1 | CODE_3 == 1, 1, 0),
         Sum_grp2 = if_else(CODE_1 == 2 | CODE_2 == 2 | CODE_3 == 2, 1, 0),
         Sum_grp3 = if_else(CODE_1 == 3 | CODE_2 == 3 | CODE_3 == 3, 1, 0),
         Sum_grp4 = if_else(CODE_1 == 4 | CODE_2 == 4 | CODE_3 == 4, 1, 0),
         Sum_grp5 = if_else(CODE_1 == 5 | CODE == 5 | CODE_3 == 5, 1, 0),
         Sum_grp6 = if_else(CODE_1 == 6 | CODE_2 == 6 | CODE_3 == 6, 1, 0),
         Missing = if_else(CODE_1 == 9 & CODE_2 == 9 & CODE_3 == 9, 1, 0))


Group_counts <- data.frame(
  Group = c("Group_1", "Group_2", "Group_3", "Group_4", "Group_5", "Group_6", "Missing"),
  Sum = c(sum(data$Sum_grp1 == 1), 
                 sum(data$Sum_grp2 == 1), 
                 sum(data$Sum_grp3 == 1),
                 sum(data$Sum_grp4 == 1),
                 sum(data$Sum_grp5 == 1),
                 sum(data$Sum_grp6 == 1),
                 sum(data$Missing == 1)))
```

Expected output looks like this:

[image]

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: does `stri_rand_strings` come from the `stringi`-package? if so, plase include in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data in long format and use `count` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% pivot_longer(cols = -MASTER_HCU_DI) %>% count(name, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expect?

```
data %>% pivot_longer(cols = -MASTER_HCU_DI) %>% group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(value), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name      Sum
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 GROUP_1   409
2 GROUP_2   897
3 GROUP_3   900
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the following functionality outlined in the question is not addressed by the existing answers:

> Where all of someone's CODE start with a 9, they are counted as missing. Otherwise, I'd like to ignore the CODE values which start with a 9.

Here is my approach to include this functionality:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  pmap_dfr(~ table(c(...)[-1])) %>%
  set_names(~ paste0("Group_", .x)) %>%
  mutate(Missing = ifelse(`Group_9` == 3, 1, NA)) %>%
  select(-`Group_9`) %>%
  colSums(na.rm = T) %>%
  tibble::tibble(Group = names(.), Sum = .) %>%
  arrange(Group)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Group     Sum
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 Group_1    23
2 Group_2    13
3 Group_3    16
4 Group_4    13
5 Group_5    13
6 Group_6    11
7 Missing    15
```

Data used:

```
data <- structure(list(MASTER_HCU_DI = c("VBHT228", "CAAO199", "NDDI124", "AVZV996", "KMOP513", "AALT248", "IGZC617", "ZDHO229", "GXYV745", "PDTW465", "SEPM505", "ZJWQ323", "VRRU692", "NHOY962", "BBFR276", "NVML939", "VHPV534", "YTXG467", "BOCT360", "ONEO498", "CICL849", "SAIK461", "NZGL739", "NIFD497", "XMVE276", "JHZM922", "LCLV707", "BPKN209", "YTZU211", "LUNI891", "CQTC089", "FBDZ269", "VKCI112", "BLJH968", "LLML439", "TDRV973", "RTFR863", "GZAN917", "WSUI006", "JILN883", "CAHM719", "JCMI028", "BGFZ774", "BGVZ374", "WBUJ792", "DLVT690", "AVKE534", "TDPU030", "SKFI697", "UCLY688", "OODZ687", "IIPR924", "TSES431", "CQSN693", "ZQGJ398", "FMGH661", "ZORF207", "MDWD343", "OBDM142", "SATV193", "MUKZ136", "INAE029", "MWDB125", "JUXN395", "LQGW143", "ALKP557", "WQAR962", "UYZI622", "WKYM520", "WUMH621", "GLRV451", "ISHG990", "OCNW161", "WQMS244", "UQEF227", "IAEZ636", "TEZJ280", "GCCJ844", "EVTF869", "JGJH568", "MDPH890", "EHKR422", "NBIM361", "XEWM477", "PBJP921", "FGEG840", "UJOO120", "XZTB081", "GXCQ610", "ANAR117", "TNIP023", "GLFN787", "SYYV532", "GOTY296", "TXME798", "SUZK405", "VWHY631", "HAXW159", "CCJN761", "GGUN719"), GROUP_1 = c(6, 1, 4, 9, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 9, 4, 3, 1, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3, 3, 3, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 9, 6, 1, 5, 9, 5, 9, 5, 5, 1, 2, 9, 1, 3, 9, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1, 4, 1, 6, 4, 5, 2, 6, 4, 1, 5, 9, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 9, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 6, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 6, 9, 3, 4, 2, 9, 6, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 4, 9), GROUP_2 = c(9, 9, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9), GROUP_3 = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gather`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
 gather('name', 'value', -MASTER_HCU_DI) %>%
 count(name, value)
```